# Batch File - Get list value using index key

Tags: batch-file

I have written a script to bat file that will print the random value from list.
but I am facing problem to access list value using it's index

My code is:

```
   set list=A B C D a b c
   echo %list[3]%
   for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do (
    @set /a bottomlimit = 0
    @set /a upperlimit = 5
    @set /a num = !bottomlimit! + !RANDOM! %% !upperlimit! - !bottomlimit! + 1
    echo %list[!num!]%   
    TIMEOUT /T 5
   )
```

Waiting for your valuable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just three options. Number one to handle your approach. Number two for a "pure" array in environment variables. Number three will mix the two, definition of the list as in option 1, but iterating the list to generate the array in option 2.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    REM OPTION 1 - The list
    echo -------------------------------------------------

    setlocal

    set "list=A B C D a b c"

    set /a bottomlimit=0
    set /a upperlimit=6

    for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do (
        set /a "num=!bottomlimit! + ( !RANDOM! %% (!upperlimit! - !bottomlimit! + 1))"
        set "pos=0"
        for %%l in (!list!) do if defined pos if !pos!==!num! ( echo %%l & set "pos=" ) else ( set /a "pos+=1")
    )   

    endlocal


    REM OPTION 2 - The "pure" array
    echo -------------------------------------------------

    setlocal 

    set "list[0]=A"
    set "list[1]=B"
    set "list[2]=C"
    set "list[3]=D"
    set "list[4]=a"
    set "list[5]=b"
    set "list[6]=c"

    set /a bottomlimit=0
    set /a upperlimit=6

    for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do (
        set /a "num=!bottomlimit! + ( !RANDOM! %% (!upperlimit! - !bottomlimit! + 1))"
        for %%n in (!num!) do echo !list[%%n]!
    )   

    endlocal



    REM OPTION 3 - The remix
    echo -------------------------------------------------

    setlocal

    set "list=A B C D a b c"

    set "pos=0"
    for %%l in (!list!) do ( set "list[!pos!]=%%l" & set /a "pos+=1" )

    set /a "bottomlimit=0"
    set /a "upperlimit=!pos!-1"

    for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do (
        set /a "num=!bottomlimit! + ( !RANDOM! %% (!upperlimit! - !bottomlimit! + 1))"
        for %%n in (!num!) do echo !list[%%n]!
    )   

    endlocal


    endlocal 
    exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks MC ND it help me to sort out my problem

Comment: @AnupamSharma: Where?

Comment: I think in these line of code 

for %%l in (%list%) do ( set "list[!pos!]=%%l" & set /a "pos+=1" )

Comment: This is in below line 

set /a "upperlimit=%pos%-1"

when I replace this line with set /a "upperlimit=20" to test will give me echo is off in console on the place of value

Comment: @AnupamSharma: And what have you changed? This line does not have a division and i've repeated the code in answer 10000 times (literal) and get no error.

Comment: My code is below 
for %%l in (%list%) do ( set "list[!pos!]=%%l" & set /a "pos+=1" )

    set /a "bottomlimit=0"
    set /a "upperlimit=20"

    for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do (
     set /a "num=%bottomlimit% + ( !RANDOM! %% (!upperlimit! - !bottomlimit! + 1))"
     for %%n in (!num!) do echo !list[%%n]!
    )

Comment: @AnupamSharma: No list, what kind of content does it have? No initialization for pos. Why 20? Is the code inside a block? If it is, vairable access should change.

Comment: @AnupamSharma: Changed code in answer so all access to variables is delayed, so including it inside a block will have no efect.

Comment: I found out the error but not solution, Actually I am using your code in for loop getting data from file "for /F "tokens=2-3 delims=<>" %%a in (%LOGFILE%) do (" when i remove this loop it works fine

Comment: @AnupamSharma: create new question and include code, sample of data processed and expected output. So we could see why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set list=A B C D a b c
  set /a counter=1
   for %%a in (%list%) do (
    set "list[!counter!]=%%~a"
    set /a counter=counter+1
   )
   set list[


   for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do (
    @set /a bottomlimit = 0
    @set /a upperlimit = 5
    @set /a num = bottomlimit + !RANDOM! %% upperlimit - bottomlimit + 1
    for %%# in (!num!) do echo !list[%%#]!  
    TIMEOUT /T 5
   )
   endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `echo/%list:~3,1%`, but you can't use `echo/%list:~%num%,1%`

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "list=ABCDabc"
echo/%list:~3,1%
 set /a bottomlimit = 0
 set /a upperlimit = 5
for /l %%a in (1,1,6) do (
 CALL:CALC
 CALL _temp.bat
 Timeout /t 5
)
del _temp.bat
pause >nul
exit/b
:CALC
set /a num = %bottomlimit% + %random% %% %upperlimit% - %bottomlimit% + 1
 echo/set "list=%list%">_temp.bat
 echo/echo/%%list:~%num%,1%%>>_temp.bat
exit/b
```